# How can I use geom_hline between two points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a Ramachandran plot and I'd like to draw a line between two points. I'm using this code:

```
 ggplot(result) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180,180), breaks = seq(-180,180,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-180,180), breaks = seq(-180,180,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
  geom_hex(aes(x, y), bins = 500) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour="red", linetype = "longdash") +
  scale_fill_gradientn("", colours = rev(rainbow(10, end = 4/6))) + ylab(expression(paste(psi))) + xlab(expression(paste(phi)))
```

And I have this:

[image]

But I'd like to put another two horizontal lines like this figure:

[image]

I used hline but don't know how to define it between two points.

Comment: In base or lattice graphic a "line" between two points is called a "segment". There does appear to be a geom_segment gglot2 function. 162 hits for search on `[r] ggplot2 segment`

Comment: @42- Yes!. Thank you, I found it the answer with segment.

Answer (score 4):

Using `geom_segment`

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = 0, x2 = -180, y1 = 0, y2 = 0) #Data frame with the points

  ggplot(result) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180,180), breaks = seq(-180,180,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-180,180), breaks = seq(-180,180,40), expand=c(0,0)) +
  geom_hex(aes(x, y), bins = 500) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour="red", linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = "segment"), data = df)+
  scale_fill_gradientn("", colours = rev(rainbow(10, end = 4/6))) + ylab(expression(paste(psi))) + xlab(expression(paste(phi)))
```